# Replace different types of html tags from text by appropriate expressions in python

Tags: python, html, tags

I am cleaning a raw text taken from website so that it can be tokenized into clear sentences in order to train word embedding. Take one as an example:

```
Xét xử ông Đinh La Thăng và đồng phạm: Luật sư nói tránh thành án lệ</h4></li></ul></div></div><p>Ngày 14-1, tại phiên tòa xét xử sơ thẩm ông <b>Đinh La Thăng</b>, nguyên chủ tịch Hội đồng Quản trị
```

I want to replace`</h4></li></ul></div></div><p>` by **'.'**, and `<b>` by space **' '** so the string above will become like this:

```
Xét xử ông Đinh La Thăng và đồng phạm: Luật sư nói tránh thành án lệ. Ngày 14-1, tại phiên tòa xét xử sơ thẩm ông Đinh La Thăng, nguyên chủ tịch Hội đồng Quản trị
```

I have tried using beautiful soup, but I don't know how to replace each type differently and effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var =  'Xét xử ông Đinh La Thăng và đồng phạm: Luật sư nói tránh thành án lệNgày 14-1, tại phiên tòa xét xử sơ thẩm ông Đinh La Thăng, nguyên chủ tịch Hội đồng Quản trị'
```

> soup = BeautifulSoup(var, 'html.parser')
>   print soup.get_text()

In this way you get the pure text, without the need anymore to replace.

Comment: I need to separate it into lists of sentences in order to train word embedding. Doing your way can only remove the tags

Answer (score 0):

babatto's answer is clean if you wish to remove all headers from the raw html file, but if you wish to `replace` them as described from your question, you can try this:

```
var = """Xét xử ông Đinh La Thăng và đồng phạm: Luật sư nói tránh thành án lệ</h4></li></ul></div></div><p>Ngày 14-1, tại phiên tòa xét xử sơ thẩm ông <b>Đinh La Thăng</b>, nguyên chủ tịch Hội đồng Quản trị"""

replacements = {
"</h4></li></ul></div></div><p>": ".",
"</b>": ""
}

for key in replacements.keys():
    if key in var:
        var = var.replace(key,replacements[key])

print(var)
```

Comment: I need to separate the texts into lists of sentences in order to train word embedding. For example, I need to replace the high light tags with space, and other tags with dot. However, It seems like there are lots of types of html tags so i don't know how to clean then separate the text clearly

Comment: @NguyễnThếQuý Could you give an example in the question? You can still use the method I've specified by manually filling the dict `replacements` with whatever char you want.